# How to keep N/A as N/A when using an ifelse statement?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am recoding a `df` with columns containing "yes," "no," or "N/A." I want to recode "yes" as 1, "no" as 0, and keep "N/A" as "N/A."

I have written the following code:

```
df$first_column <-ifelse(df$first_column=="yes",1,0)
```

However, this replaces `N/A` with `0`. What is the easiest way to get around this problem?

Here is reproducible `df`:

```
structure(list(first_column = c("yes", "no", "N/A", "yes")), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with either a nested ifelse if we want to avoid any packages

```
df$first_column <- ifelse(df$first_column == "N/A", "N/A", 
     ifelse(df$first_column == "yes",1,0))
```

-output

```
df$first_column
[1] "1"   "0"   "N/A" "1"
```

NOTE: `"N/A"` is not `NA`.  It is better to convert to `NA` as the `"N/A"` is character and this will change the integer expected binary column to character.  Better will be

```
with(df, replace(first_column, first_column == "N/A", NA) == "yes")
[1]  TRUE FALSE    NA  TRUE
```

---

Or could use `recode`

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
   mutate(first_column = recode(first_column, yes = 1, no = 0))
```

-output

```
  first_column
1            1
2            0
3           NA
4            1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid nested `if_else`

```
df <-mutate(df, first_column = case_when(first_column=="yes" ~ 1,
                                         first_column=="no" ~ 0,
                                         T ~ first_column))
```